# UILocalNotification - Later

Tags: ios4, uilocalnotification

In my application I am using UILocalNotification which works fine. But I need "Later" button in the alert instead of "Cancel". When the user clicks on the "Later" button I want to show the notification after sometime. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No man, you are on the wrong way.Due to the limitations of iphoneSDK such thing is not possible.In local notification it will only show the two buttons in alert View.

```
1)Cancel
2)View
```

Still you can rename the View button to you wish:

```
localNotif.alertAction = @"Snooze";
```

rahter than renaming the Cancel button.